# How to drop a partition of a table before 6 months ago

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, partition

There is a table in my database and I will create a partition for this table each day, the rows for each day are nearly 10e7.

Is there a way to drop the oldest partition directly?

Because I got in trouble with switch the oldest partition to a new table, the code is shown as below:

```
alter table dbo.TempData switch partition 1 to dbo.TempCleanBuffer
```

My SQL Server always reminds me that the two Clustered Indexes of the two tables are not identically after I execute the code. I've already created the new table on the same filegroup with the partition I want to switch.

If I can't drop the partition directly, how can I fix the problem properly?

Comment: sorry, I used the wrong word.

Comment: As the error tells you: the Indexes are not identical. As far as I know, in order to switch partitions, the table structrue (including indexes, collation, order of columns, nullability of columns and so on) has to be 100% identical. If this is given, the switch should work. However, I am not sure but I guess you will have to add the destination partiton in your alter statement as well.

Comment: The two tables are all built on the same filegroup, the properties of all the columns are also identical. The only difference I could found is that the index of the new table has an extra code bulk 'on RealTimeData20201212', (RealTimeData20201212) is the filegroup which the new table built-in.

Comment: All indexes need to be in the same respective filegroups (obvious if you think about it, as it's just a metadata change, swapping the table id's of the partitions, no data moves)